# Event Calendar For asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I am working on an event based project, where I will be storing my events with a start date or I can say event date with start and end time in my SQL SERVER through Entity Framework.

In the mean time I want to highlight the date of the event in my frontend. How do I do that? I do not want to do it with **Day pilot** or **DHTMX** or **Telerik**. I just want something which just highlights the dates of events, and if possible further to see the events in my deck.

[image]

I would like the calendar to look like this.

Comment: Have you marked any of your previous questions as answered? You have asked 10 questions to date on StackOverflow and have not marked any as answered. You will find that you get more people replying to your questions if you bother to mark them as answered.

Comment: Hi Seanya, Yes i asked many questions, and many things are still not resolved, and few helped me so i replied them with a thank you note, and now on wards i will do it. thanks you for giving me suggesting me.

Comment: In this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825378/error-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring you even say "it worked". You are not working with StackOverflow here.  have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and you will get much more replies to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

jQuery UI datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
example: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html

**Option 2:**
I have used this control for date / schedule based stuff before. Really big fan of their functionality: http://mvc.daypilot.org/

Also, DayPilot Lite is free too.

Comment: As i mentioned, i dont want to show the timings and all, initially i need something like a calendar which should be highlighted on the date of events. is there anything like that.

Comment: What does "timings" mean?

Comment: Sorry for not describing my problem properly, i want a calendar control more like ajax calendar extender , which should  highlight the date of event which  is in database.

Comment: I would have thought that this is exactly what you were looking for: http://code.daypilot.org/62492/scheduler-for-asp-net-mvc-4-razor

Comment: I edited my question with an image , which am i working on it.hope you will get what i am expecting.

Comment: Thanks Seanya84, but my calendar is static, it will be displayed in my  page, only thing is it should highlight with the date.any how thanks for suggestion, and if you get any idea in future please post it to me.